# Get input value from a template jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a template

```
<div id="template" style="display: none;">
  <strong>Name</strong>: <span class="name"></span><br/>
  <input type="number" id="amount">  
  <button type="button" onclick="App.submit()">submit</button>         
</div>
```

which can be used to generate multiple divs

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {  
   var list = $('#list');
   var template = $('#template');
   template.find('.name').text(i); 
   list.append(template.html());         
 }
```

When submit button is clicked from one of the divs, how can I get its `name` and input's `amount` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap those elements in a container so you can keep instances isolated and add some classes to make finding the elements simpler within that new container instance

Note you can't repeat `id=amount` since id's must be unique.

Then delegate a click listener instead of using `onclick`

HTML

```
<div id="template" style="display: none;">
  <div class="input-row">
    <strong>Name</strong>: <span class="name"></span><br/>
    <input type="number" class="amount">
    <button type="button" class="row-submit" >submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.row-submit', function(){
    // the new row wrapper
    var $row = $(this).closest('.input-row'),
        // find the elements within this row instance
        name = $row.find('.name').text(),
        amount = $row.find('.amount').val();

        // do something with the values            

        // then do your app submit
        App.submit()

});
```